# How much exact are the operations in CGAL function "halfspace intersection with constructions"

Tags: intersection, predicate, cgal, convex-hull, inexact-arithmetic

I want to compare my own algorithm with CGAL's halfspace intersection algorithm in terms of their speed performance. Since I did my own operations with double, I obtain inexact constructions of points and lines. Also I use inexact predicates. **In order to get a fair comparison, I also want CGAL's operations to work with double, to produce inexact constructions and to use inexact predicates**. I chose **Simple_cartesian<double> kernel**, defined my planes with this kernel and declared my variable to hold the output mesh as Surface_mesh of this kernel's points. I call **halfspace_intersection_with_construction_3()** function  I am still not sure whether these specifications are sufficient for CGAL to do everything inexact? I am suspecious of whether it changes operations to exact forms to be robust despete my specifications. The reason I think so is I get almost the same speed performance with the version where I use exact_predicates_inexact_constructions kernel.
Should I give some traits class as argument? Actually I did not understand much how the traits class work.

Comment: No exact construction will be perform neither with EPICK nor SImple_cartesian<double>. Out of curiosity, is it a new algorithm or a faster implementation that you are having?

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the thing that I want to learn is why CGAL's performance almost remains the same? In all cases, does it hold the computations with rationals (even when Simple_cartesian<double> is used for definitions) to preserve the robustness, for instance? By the way, yes, I am testing a new algorithm. I want the computations to be fair whether they crash robustness or not.